# Deploying Smart Device Project into SD Card

Tags: sql, vb.net, windows-ce

Greeting,

I'm having difficulty deploying my Smart Device Project into the SD Card of my MC2180. My application uses Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition v3.5, and it need to be deploy on a WinCE 6.0 device (MC2180).

Now the problem is :
1) If I do a normal deploy to my device, I can set it deploy the "Application" in my SD Card, BUT the SQL still install in my Program Files, by any chance if the device got a reset my "Application" won't work anymore because SQL is not there.

2) I can create a CAB File, BUT I don't know how to include my SQL installer.

What I want is to make a CAB that can install everything nicely, OR, make the program portable :)

Please advice what can I do :) I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Regards,
Milo

Comment: Some devices have a partition from where on startup a list of cab files is read, and each is installed.

This is vendor specific. Looking at firmware image for the mc2100, for your device this folder might be named "\Application".

I can see that there are two programs running at startup of the device, which look in this directory: abstart.exe and abboot.exe. Maybe looking in this directory will give you a hint on how to add more cabs there.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to extract and repackage files in the SQL compact cab, but this may be clumsy and still have some issues if those file must be placed in the Windows folder to be found from the loader and your device configuration does not support a folder for executables on the SD card. Usually the simplest solution is to install the cab file by launching wceload every time you app starts. You can suppress the UI using the /noui command line switch. Obviously you may add a check that verifies if the files are already in place (to avoid multiple installs that will be a time waste) and you'll also need to load classes/forms etc. that reference the SQLCE modules only after you've finished the installation.

Comment: Hallow :) Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how your solution work, I never use the /noui command line thing before :( Is there a more simple solution? Is that possible that we can run another CAB when we executing one CAB?